# How to get one status update from users

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question about MySQL Query. I have a slider on the homepage to show the newest user status updates. I am using JOIN table to do this. Everything work well expect the status update is not recognize with user own status.

There is my table row:

**users**

```
id | username | name | last_login | status | date_registered
```

**posts**

```
userid | post_details | date_posted | status | facebook | twitter
```

There is my query:

```
"SELECT U.id, U.username, U.name, U.last_login, U.status, P.userid, P.post_details, P.date_posted 
 FROM users U 
 LEFT JOIN posts P ON U.id = P.userid 
 WHERE U.status='active' AND P.status='1'
 ORDER BY U.last_login DESC, 
 LIMIT 12"
```

Problem when I am using above query's user status update not recognize with ordered user slider. When I add `AND P.userid=U.id` in `WHERE` line, only 1 user is displayed.

Please tell me a better way to make status updates is recognized with user.

Preview:

[image: Preview]

Comment: According to your query, it is already filtering the status of user and status of post. Maybe you have one record for such specific filter.

Comment: Solved, I forgot to GROUP query